# Firebase PhoneAuthentication not returning verification Code

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to create a phone authentication using firebase and Angular. After setting recaptcha verifier and phone number and passed to firebase.auth.signInWithPhoneNumber() function. It returns only the verification Id and not verification code and it not sending sms to my number as well.

```
onSignInSubmit(phoneNumber) {
    this.recaptcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size' : 'invisible',
      'callback': function(response) {
        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.

      }
    });

    this.afauth.auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, this.recaptcha).then((confiramtionResult) => {
      console.log(confiramtionResult);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to ask the user for the SMS code.
After the user provides it, you call:

```
var code = getCodeFromUserInput();
confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
  // User signed in successfully.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
}).catch(function (error) {
  // Error occurred.
});
```

Comment: I gave my phone number as a user, but i didn't recieved any sms from the firebase

Comment: Are you using a whitelisted phone number? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers

Comment: I am using the whitelisted phone number but it didn''t follow the few steps in  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers Thanks for the information